# jQuery: run css related method AFTER previous css method is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am doing the following through jQuery, but it looks like they are almost happening simultaneously.

Is there a way to make sure itemNameContainer.removeClass('NoDisplay') in the complete callback to run only after the loadingContainer.addClass('NoDisplay') is completed?

Visually, it looks like I am seeing 'Please wait..' and the item name show up at the same time..

```
function onToggleItemCompletionStatus(currentItem) {
    var itemId, toggle = !currentItem.Completed,
        loadingContainer, itemNameContainer;
    itemId = currentItem.ItemId;
    loadingContainer = $('#loading_' + itemId);
    itemNameContainer = $('#name_' + itemId);

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            loadingContainer.removeClass('noDisplay');
            itemNameContainer.addClass('noDisplay');
        },
        complete: function (xhr, textStatus) {
            loadingContainer.addClass('noDisplay');
            itemNameContainer.removeClass('noDisplay');
        },
        data: {
            accessToken: aToken,
            listId: currentGroceryList.Id,
            itemId: currentItem.ItemId,
            completed: toggle
        },
        dateType: 'json',
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $.publish(customEvent.ItemToggledFail, [currentItem]);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            var success = data.success;

            if (success) {
                $.publish(customEvent.ItemToggledSuccess, [currentItem]);
            } else {
                $.publish(customEvent.ItemToggledFail, [currentItem]);
            }
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: actionUrls.toggleItemCompletionStatus
    });
}
```

**EDIT**
I pasted the actual function to give a better idea

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me...is the request synchronous or asynchronous?  Can you post the rest of the $.ajax call?  Is the response just arriving very quickly?

Comment: They should be performed in a matter of microseconds, so a callback isn't given. There is no *after CSS applied* hook that I know of. You could be hacky with `setTimeout()`, but I often don't recommend it.

Comment: I guess everything is just happening in a matter of microseconds..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of, but you could try...

```
loadContainer.fadeOut(300, function() {
   itemNameContainer.removeClass('NoDisplay');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this approach makes the transition appear smoother. It's not perfect, but everything is happening in a matter of microseconds anyway.